# git revert and do not remove the pre-commit

Tags: git

say, I have 3 commits, now I do not want release the commit 2 and 3. But I need those commit, because I may be release those feature in the future. So I can't use `git reset` since that will remove history commits, and the `git revert` require a commit range, are there any other easy way?
See the below, I like the commit 1 as a new commit 4 behind the commit 3

**1 <- 2 <- 3**

**1 <- 2 <- 3 <- 4(1)**

Comment: Make another branch from (4). Rebase and drop commits 2 and 3 from _that_ branch, and release that branch.

Comment: Alternatively, if it's just the one commit you need, then checkout `1`, cherry-pick `4`, and create a new branch